# Destructor to call free() to free dynamically allocated memory using malloc

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, constructor, destructor

In C++, if I have some dynamically allocated memory using malloc, can I free the same by calling free() from destructor and then explicitly call the destructor via class object?

Trying to do that but getting an exception.

Is it now allowed?

So here I'm explicitly calling the destructor. Is this allowed? I mean, I'm calling it to free memory. I did read that after the scope, the destructor is called implicitly. Does this mean the free() will try to happen twice?

My code snippet:

```
class School
{
    int a;
};

class Test
{
    public:
    School* school;
    void Run()
    {
        school = (School*)malloc(sizeof(School));
    }
    
    ~Test()
    {
        if (NULL != school)
        {
            free(school);
            school = NULL;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.Run();
    t.~Test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which destructor are you calling? Can you show some code?

Comment: Use `new`/`delete` and don't call the destructor yourself, look into smart pointers, it would save you some work. Show us your code for better assessment.

Comment: Not only is calling `free` to release memory acquired via `malloc` allowed, it is the only correct way to do it. But in C++ you should generally not be using `malloc` in the first place. If you are getting an exception or a crash, then there is an error in your code, but it isn't from passing a `malloc`ed pointer to `free`. Please share a [MCVE]. Otherwise, it is very difficult to guess where you went wrong.

Comment: Yes, let me share. One minute.

Comment: Added the code snippet.

Comment: So here I'm explicitly calling the destructor. Is this allowed? I mean, I'm calling it to free memory. I did read that after the scope, the destructor is called implicitly. Does this mean the free() will try to happen twice?

Comment: The destructor is automatically called at the end of the scope. Don't do this.

Comment: So should there be an issue if I call it myself again? Getting an exception in some cases because of this.

Comment: So, just to clarify, if my destructor function is not empty (containing free() or some other lines of code), the same would be automatically invoked at the end of scope. Right? And if I do still call it, can you help understand why there is usually an issue? @tkausl

Comment: Its an issue because its undefined behavior to call it twice, which here happens.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, another thing, would appreciate some insight. Sometimes, I see free() is directly working but when called from destructor, it throws an exception. Any cause for that? I'm not calling the destructor explicitly in this case but seems like there's some issue in having free() inside a destructor.

Comment: @Curiosity There could be many issues. Without seeing the code, there's no way for us to know what issue that particular code might have.

Comment: It's in the code above. Except that I comment out t.~Test(); (didn't call the destructor explicitly which I get is wrong). But there is still some exception in Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: @Curiosity The *only* time you should *ever* call a destructor directly is when an object has been constructed using [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which you are not doing here.

Comment: @Curiosity I can make the class fall apart with a one line program: `int main() {Test t;}`  Then here it falls apart with a three line program: `int main()  { Test t. t.Run(); Test t2 = t; }`.

Comment: That is because `Test::school` is not initialized in that scenario, so calling `free(school)` in `~Test()` is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: But it also checks for the memory being not NULL before attempting to free it (if statement). So if Test::school is uninitialized in the sense of not having memory allocated, it will be NULL and free() won't be operated on it.

Comment: @Curiosity *it will be NULL* -- No.  Uninitialized means it could have any value.  The value of that pointer could be null, it could be `0x67833278`, it could be `0x00000001`, you don't know.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. It's not allocated but not NULL too.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code destroys `t` twice. It is destroyed first when you call the destructor and then again when it goes out of scope. You cannot create one object and then destroy two objects.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this part now.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call the destructor, and that has sense whenever you create the object using an *placement new*.

You may get an exception if you have the opposite order of operations. First you need to call the destructor, as it needs to free all the resources that the object may have allocated. You need to call the `free` function only after all resources of the object are deallocated/destroyed. For example:

```cpp
struct S {
    ~S() {
        delete ptr;
    }
    int *ptr;
};

int main() {
    char *buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(S)) ;
    S *s = new (buf)S();
    // Do not call free here as the destructor needs to access the s.ptr:
    //free(buf);
    s->~S();
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```